# What is recommended data type and encryption type for password in a database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I want to know what data type and encryption type best to use in a database for user passwords. Thank you in advance.

Comment: WordPress uses [`md5`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam, Thanks , can we use another type in wordpress such as SHA1 and other types?

Comment: You can jump start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1045988/1743124

Comment: WordPress already handles encrypting passwords (_not_ just using md5, by the way). Why are you asking? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I am trying to create a table in myphpadmin for users and their passwords. So I ask what data type should I used and encryption type for password security.

Comment: Why are you doing that? WordPress already has a user accounts system.